# primefaces tag p not being recognized

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

hello  I'm learning primefaces and I have been trying to create a `<p:fileUpload` tag but eclipse just  tells me that the tag is unknown, and when I run on server  an error is thrown, I already imported the `commons-io ,  fileupload  and  primefaces  jars` and  added the libraries to the `webinf/lib` through the  `deployment assembly` option,  but still nothing,  the `web.xml` is configured also,  so what am i doing wrong?

(EDIT) PAGE CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 

<h:head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/nuevaEtapa.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</h:head> 
<body>
    <h1>Nueva Etapa</h1>
    <a class="links" href="Administrador.xhtml">Administrador</a>    
    <div id="response"></div>
    <h:form class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">             
        <div class="input-wrapper" >
            <h:inputText value="#{etapaBean.origen}"  class="inputs" />
            <h:inputText value="#{etapaBean.destino}"  class="inputs" />
            <h:inputText value="#{etapaBean.fecha}"  class="inputs" />
            <h:inputText value="#{etapaBean.hora}"  class="inputs" />
            <h:inputText value="#{etapaBean.categoria}"  class="inputs" />
            <h:inputText value="#{etapaBean.tipo}"  class="inputs" />
            <h:inputText value="#{etapaBean.nomPuerto}"  class="inputs" />
            <h:inputText value="#{etapaBean.alturaPto}"  class="inputs" />
            <h:inputText value="#{etapaBean.nomMapa}"  class="inputs" />
            <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.upload}"  allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"  description="Select Images" ></p:fileUpload>
    <img src="" class="imagen" width="200px" />
        </div>  
        <h:commandButton class="btn" action="#{etapaBean.guardarEtapa()}" value="Guardar Etapa" id="cmdbtn" />
    </h:form>               
</body> 
</html>
```

WEB.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
 <display-name>ProyectoUCI-2015</display-name>
 <!--
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
-->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
<filter>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: can you please show the full code of **nuevaEtapa.xhtml**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have primefaces namespace setup in the page, something like this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

Comment: thank you,  but  now  the error is gone  but the `input file` is not showing.

Comment: Try replacing `<body>` with `<h:body>`

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, but try getting the basic example to work. You can start [here](http://www.primefaces.org/gettingStarted)

Answer (score 0):

Put the fileUploader in a separate form with enctype="multipart/form-data". And the rest of the code in other form without the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data". And use < h:body >.